# Why does area have display none?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a huge issue caused by the default style in google chrome. 
The default dispay for `area` tag is none. But the area/map is still rendered.

http://jsfiddle.net/hm826/1/

Everything works fine when I apply a css display inline or block. 
I am interested to know why the default is none in chrome? Is there any reason? Can I apply the display inline without any implications? How is the element rendered if it is not displayed?

I use the newest Google chrome on windows 7.

[image]

Comment: your fiddle working fine in google chrome without display inline or block setting.

Comment: Yep, seems fine for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `area` element isn't displayed because it's an kind of abstraction to add multiple links/anchors onto one image instead of multiple images with a lot of anchors.

If something is shown e.g. a background color in that `area` tag you can't see the image anymore where the map was overlayed.

There are a lot of things where elements have a kind of initial style given by the browser and I guess it's just to give developers the information that this element is not shown.

**Example:**
Added a new fiddle based on given example which shows this property is not set in real when I try to get the property with javascript/jquery.

In Chrome I get an `undefined`

So it's fact it's just a helper in DEV tools.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExNGj/

Comment: That means that I can safely set the display as long as I make sure it won't obstruct the image?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so because when you set display settings you need to handle also things like positioning/floating etc. Tried to add borders and those boders were outside the image. Best practice in the html4 age was to change the image when hovering an area to get effects for this map.

Comment: FYI I set display to block and it works perfect just as it works in other browsers.

Comment: @Dharman Thats correct but if you add e.g. border:solid 1px #f00 you'll see it's beyond the image (but still clickable on the image)

Comment: but that is only because you have added it a width. This creates unexpected behaviour. I will just be careful to never give it any dimensions.